# Is Harry related to Ginny by blood?

Tags: harry-potter

In Order of the Phoenix, Sirius confesses he is related to the Weasleys, and that all Pureblood families are related to one another. I was thinking about this, and realized that James Potter was from a Pureblood family.

**Who is Harry related to, and does he end up married to his 4th cousin twice removed?**

Comment: well on the harry potter wiki i looks like harry has at least one potter ancestor that was a black.

Comment: @Himarm The term is Black British, please. /s

Comment: The Potters were not pure bloods... or at least named on the Sacred 28, which although was biased, did include the Weasleys and Blacks.

Comment: Looks a bit too broad after the recent edit though. What are you asking for, Harry's entire family tree going back to the Middle Ages and forward again to his nth cousins?

Comment: I added a few words to the question to keep it limited in scope; I fear it would be re-closed as ‘too broad’ without a bit of narrowing down. Hope you don’t mind. @randal'thor Jinx!

Comment: @randal'thor As far back as is feasibly known on implied would be preferred, but as much information as possible.

Comment: If you're going to change the question that drastically after it already got a great answer, then it would probably be best to just accept it and ask a new question. (You get more rep, and we avoid well-researched answers becoming irrelevant.

Comment: The question as it stands is super-broad. Harry is related to the entire Weasley family tree (through Ginny) which makes him related to the entire Black family tree and then the Prewetts, Malfoys, and practically all named  pureblood characters.

Comment: This should be a new question, not an edit that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @CreationEdge The edit _didn’t_ actually invalidate the existing answer; even though the focus of the question changed, the existing answer addresses the edited question very well, too.

Comment: @ibid Given the way the question is asked, I think it’s safe to assume that it’s talking about relation by blood only, not by marriage.

Comment: @Janus I disagree. The accepted answer currently focuses on just analyzing a single relationship, trying to find its connection. It's a good answer, but essentially incomplete. They shouldn't have to edit to address the new question completely. A new question and answer hurts nothing, and gives everyone a chance to earn more rep at minimum.

Comment: @Anoplexian Your recent edit invalidated the answer to this question so I've [rolled it back to the original version per SE policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167070/doesnt-the-asker-have-the-right-to-modify-his-question). Since the original version was a duplicate, I've closed it as well. Feel free to ask a new question with what you intended to ask, although in this case you need to be careful not to make it too broad.

Comment: @Null The question originally asked about Harry's relations, and only made a mention of Ginny in the question (and obviously the title that I used as clickbait). I'm not quite sure how it would invalidate the answer, as it already answers the question, and adds a note about the duplication.

Comment: @CreationEdge Please read the original question. The first part is specifically addressed with the question, and is still addressed when the question is edited to remove the duplicated part. It specifically asks **Who is Harry related to....** and continues to ask the duplicate. By removing the duplicate part, it gives the answer (which answers **both** questions) the same effect.

Comment: @ibid Please see the comments above for the reasoning. The question was **not** changed drastically, only edited for clarity.

Comment: Anoplexian, please do not change the essence of the question after posting it, especially when an answer is already posted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**We don't know**. Sirius correctly notes that all Wizarding families are related, so he is almost certainly related to every other non-Muggle-born in the series. Harry is therefore almost guaranteed to be related to Ginny, but only in the same way that [all Britons are descendants of Charlemagne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNE_1XvJo6g).

The furthest back in Harry's Wizarding blood we know about were [his grandparents, Euphemia and Fleamont Potter, and his great-grandfather Henry Potter](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-potter-family). Rowling never gives Euphemia and Henry's wife's maiden names, although both were presumably pure-blood witches since James was considered pure-blooded. So we know Harry's relations to fellow wizards could be relatively recent, but have no idea who they would be.

There is a Charlus Potter [listed on the Black Family tree](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/blackfamilytrees/official-final-version.gif), who had a son with Dorea Black (1920-1977). Before Pottermore, people thought he was Harry's grandfather. If that had been true, Harry would be relatively closely related to Ginny, but Pottermore put a kibosh on that.

If Charlus only had a son, that would mean that the son and his grandchildren's last name would be Potter. Given the timeline, that would mean it's very, very unlikely that any living witches and wizards who are descendants of this branch of the Potters, since no one ever really mentions or brings up the Sacksville-Potters.

The absolute closest Harry could be related to another character is as a second cousin, if either Euphemia or Fleamont had siblings. So the good news is that at the very least, Harry's marriage is legal.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be legal? Even first cousins can marry in the UK, and our info on pureblood families indicates that Wizarding law is likely the same.

Comment: Well, technically, the _furthest back_ we know about is Linfred, in the 12th century. Henry is only the furthest back we have an unbroken line of named wizards (presuming here that the Potter name, like most English names up until the 20th century was carried only through the male line).